# How to override the InputMethodService method onEvaluateInputViewShown()?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am trying to override the onEvaluateInputViewShown()  but I am not being able to run my service, as even setting the return value of this function to true does not make the softkeyboard to show.

Manifest:

```
    <service android:name="softKeyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Service implementation:

```
public class softKeyboard extends InputMethodService  {

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public  boolean onEvaluateInputViewShown(){
    super.onEvaluateInputViewShown();
    return true;
}
}
```

Finally, I start it in my activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, softKeyboard.class);
        startService(intent);
```

I would really appreciate any feedback. I have also tried to bind this service to the activity but I was not able to.